# Highcharts longshot, Set stylistically different gridLines for weekends..?

Tags: highcharts

long shot question here!

My chart has 3 views, in one of the views it shows the days of the month (1-31 etc)

My client wants to the highlight the Y-axis gridLines of days that are weekends, to be a darker color.

The other caveat is, I can't specify the stylistically different gridLines when creating the graph, only when I redraw the graph.

(Because this view isn't the initially view and I am redrawing me graph as the user navigates through the views.

ATM between redraws I am removing the old series, adding a new one, changing the chart title etc

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: From what you described, this sounds fairly plausible.  Do you have a link to an image of what you are looking for?  I am just trying to figure out what you mean by highlighting the gridlines.

Comment: unfortunately i can't share the image because its a commercial product under NDA at the moment, basically in my chart code I am setting, gridLineColor: '#bfbfc0', gridLineDashStyle: 'ShortDash', gridLineWidth: '1'. But for certain grid lines I want to just have a slightly dark color :_0

Comment: Having a hard time envisioning what your client is asking for, and if I am understanding what they want, then what they want doesn't seem like a recipe for a decent graph. Maybe you want to make use of plot bands? api: http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#xAxis-plotBands  api example: http://jsfiddle.net/fdTEx/

Comment: @baconbestnz - Understandable - been there myself - it just makes it really difficult to help.  I was thinking the same thing mg1075 was about the plotbands but was trying to get a better feel for your end goal.

Comment: Thanks both of you guys for your answers. The plotbands things looks like it could be a decent alternative. It's not what the designer put in the concept but it does illustrate the same thing, might give that a go. The graph looks great, its just a fairly complicated graph being used in a jquerymobile app. First view is the total for each month in the last year. Second view, is the days in the month tapped, the third view is an hourly break through of the point tapped haha. + You can swipe at each stage to move along a day / month depending on your scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I think that @mg1075's solution of using the plot bands is the best way of doing this, if you wanted to get really crazy you can modify the gridlines through the dom.  For example, make every other line red:

```
$.each($('.highcharts-grid path'), 
  function(i, elem) {     
     if (i % 2 != 0)
     {
        $(elem).attr('stroke','red');
     }
   });
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/UwST6/2/).

Comment: Thanks for this Mark! very interesting I think your right I'll go for the plotBands solution as its a bit more sensibile, if the designer kicks up a fuss I'll look into this :) Although I am now dating the designer so maybe I can get away with it :)

Comment: Credit should really go to @mg1075 for this.  And dating the designer might make her fussier!

Comment: I've given @mg1075 +1 but I don't think I can give any more credit to him?

Comment: Think I'll mark my answer as correct anyway as it actually answers my question more precisely I guess

Comment: Have marked this correct, after being unable to remove a drawing bug from the plotLines path. Basically SVG or highcharts or something is producing plotBands of a slightly different  width when you are trying to draw incredible small plotBands.